# Show that $G$ is a complete or empty graph on n vertices if and only if every transposition of $\{1, 2, . . . , n\} $ belongs to $Aut(G)$.

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-group

Here $Aut(G)$ is the set of all Automorphisms of the graph $G$. One direction of the proof is easy as for all empty or complete graph, every permutation of the vertex set will belong to the set of Automorphisms. However I can't see why the converse is true. Please help me out or point out how to proceed as I am very new to this area.

Comment: Is the converse statement: "For all permutations of the vertex set that belong to the set of Automorphisms, every graph is empty or complete"?

Comment: The converse will be, if every transposition of the vertex set belongs to Aut(G), then it's complete or empty graph

Comment: I suppose it is true in that case as if it is a complete graph, transposing it will make it a complete graph in the other sense. If it is empty it will remain empty. It is something along these lines?

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you make it clear?

Comment: For example, in a complete square graph, if you transpose this graph, it will still be a complete square graph. Same goes for any empty graph.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. A transposition is a length 2 - cycle in Permutation group S_n.

Comment: Can you give an example for the length 2 cycle in Permutation group S_n?

Comment: Take any cycle (1,2) or (2,3)

Comment: Wouldn't a cycle be, for example: (1,2), (2,3), (3,1)?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that the automorphism group of $G$ contains all transpositions of vertices. Then it contains all permutations of vertices (since the set of transpositions generates $S_n$).

If $G$ does not have any edges, then $G$ is $E_n$ and we are done. Otherwise, $G$ has an edge between two vertices $u$ and $v$. Then $G$ also has an edge between all other pairs $(x,y)$ of (distinct) vertices: take any automorphism which maps $u$ to $x$ and $v$ to $y$ to see that there must be an edge between $x$ and $y$. So in this case, $G$ must be $K_n$.